# Execution failed for task 'app:mergeDebugResources', could not delete path errors

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to run my Android Studio project on another computer. But when I try to do so, this error consistently pops up. I can't figure out what the problem is. Any help is much appreciated!

The errors include:

- Could not delete path
- Execution failed for task "app:mergeDebugResources"

[image: Issue]

Comment: If it's a different computer, does the path's directory exist? I.e. is there a Joe user dir etc?

Comment: This is a professor's computer. He checked out to the directory in Joe/summer2017, and just sent me this screenshot. He told me he tried it on 2 other computers and it also didn't work there. I'm not sure if there is a specific fix for this for all systems, but I am going to assume that everything is there in the path from the checkout.